# View / save pattern transformation (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, transform

I have a pattern in Illustrator. I have transformed the pattern (scale, rotate, etc.) within an object.

The pattern is only transformed within that object. The parent pattern remains the same.

**I want to**

- **View the transformations I have made** (e.g. 45° rotation, 95% scale)
- **Save transformed pattern as new pattern**
- **Update parent pattern to match pattern within object**

The ability to do any one of these would answer this question. The third would be similar to redefining a paragraph of character style based on current overrides in Illustrator or InDesign.

Comment: You can't. At least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Scott Yeah that's the news I expected — it just feels so precarious to have pattern fills that you can't recreate (without eyedropper) and that if you double click on the pattern you lose it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** get the data you are wanting.

However, if you utilize **Graphic Styles** you can save transformations so they can be reapplied later to other objects.

Graphic Styles are *specifically* designed to store appearance settings and then reapply them with a single click.

[Adobe Help for Graphic Styles](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html)

The only aspect you are seeking that is *not* covered by graphic styles is the "update parent pattern". This *might* be possible depending up what you are expecting. But if you edit a pattern swatch in AI.. all applications of that pattern swatch change. So combined with graphic styles, it may be possible.